# Кнопка Иконка + Текст

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать кнопку такого вида?
[image: Кнопка]

Пробовал пользоваться свойством у кнопки `drawableTop="_image_resource_"`, но это не помогло. Изображение только вылезло наверх, а текст остался по-центру.
Как можно сделать так, что-бы кнопка масштабировалась вместе с изображением внутри?

Comment: Поместите ваш `TextView` в контейнер (например, `FrameLayout`) с рамкой и гравитацией по центру

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***layout кнопки:***

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:background="@drawable/lock_button"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.35"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="LOCK"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        tools:ignore="SpUsage" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***selecor  @drawable/lock_button:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_default" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_default" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_default" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/lock_button_frame" />
</selector>
```

***@drawable/lock_button_frame***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000" />
</shape>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Сделал для вас на базе [ImageSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan). Обратите внимание на атрибут "android:textAllCaps"

[image: Внешний вид кнопки]

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
/>
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Lock\n ");
    string.setSpan( new ImageSpan(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),
            5, 6, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    button.setText(string);
```